# WD MyCloud Move files between shares

Tags: windows-7, networking, nas, home-networking

I'm experiencing trouble moving files between shares on a Western Digital MyCloud Ex 2.

Connecting with the device is no problem via

- An Android mobile device on the network using the WD MyCloud app
- SMB / Windows Explorer
- HTTP web access

To troubleshoot the issue I've made sure:

- The Bonjour service is running
- Windows Firewall is switched off
- Windows file sharing services are turned on (though this should not be relevant)

To prevent the move action taking up too much time moving the 150GB of data over the network I'm not using SMB/Windows Explorer. 
Attempting to move the folder using the Android App fails without any feedback from the app. The alternative is to use the WD MyCloud application for Windows though this fails to find the MyCloud device even though the Windows host and device are connected to the same network.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using SFTP. The MyCloud is just a Linux box under the skin and you can get SSH and FTP access (you can allow access to those services via switches on the MyCloud Network Settings). I use WinSCP for convenient SSH Session management, and an easy graphic interface.

Like any local file 'move' if you are moving even whole trees of files, it is VERY quick if it is staying on the same actual drive as it only has to rewrite the pointers to the file data. And if it is moved to a different physical drive then you are not actually having to push the data over the LAN - everything statys on the server.

Answer (score 0):

hi there the way ive just seen is to do an internal back up im moving tbs and it seems to work very fast at the moment

to do this i did the following
1, log in as admin user (on the **dashboard**)
2, go to **backups**
3, click on **internal backup**
4, click **Create Job**
5, follow the screen and just sit back and wait

mine has moved 20+ gb in 5 m

i did this on the my cloud ex4100 but should work

Comment: Can you edit and clarify a bit here though?